# UIBarButtonItem causes "Unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I call an instance to a class in my main.m to my Controls.m class but it seems to be giving me a "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Every time I hit the button it just crashes, but isn't Controls.m set to `self` in this code? It shouldn't have trouble finding the test selector action.

**Main.m**

```
- (void)loadView {
    Controls *ct = [[Controls alloc] init];
    [ct addControls];
    [ct release];
}
```

**Controls.m**

```
- (void)addControls {
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, mv.frame.size.height-60, mv.frame.size.width, 40)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnDataOverlay = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test Button" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(test)];
    NSArray *toolbarButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barBtnDataOverlay, nil];
    toolbar.items = toolbarButtons;
    [mv addSubview:toolbar];
    [barBtnDataOverlay release];
    [toolbar release];
 }

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"TEST button hit");
}
```

Comment: Move your test-method above your addControls-method and try again.

Comment: no dice that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Post the full error message.  The important part of the error is the name of the selector that was sent, and the object that couldn't respond to the selector.  Knowing both those things will tell where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ct` will be dealloced by `[ct release]` as no retain is left. Try to add a `ct` retin property to your class to keep it around.

In class definition:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) Controls *ct;
```

In your implementation:

```
@synthesize ct;
```

...

Change your loadView to something like:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.ct = [[Controls alloc] init];
    [self.ct addControls];
    [self.ct release];
}
```

Or even neater:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.ct = [[[Controls alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.ct addControls];
}
```

You should also release `ct` somewhere like in `viewDidUnload`

```
- (void)viewDidUnLoad {
    self.ct = nil;
}
```

BTW, is this in a `UIViewController` class? then the `loadView` method should probably assign the `view` instance variable. If you look in the documentation for `UIViewController` you will see this:

> If you override this method in order to create your views manually, you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the view property.

Comment: I know about the : symbol errors when they are not on a selector when the calling action has parameters. This is not one of them. It seems that in my main.m class I'm releasing the instance class too early so when I remove [ct release]; line the code works fine. When should I release this?

Comment: Ah ok. Now i see, yeah ct will be dealloced as no one has a retain on it. You should probably add ct retain @property to you class and then use self.ct = [[Controls alloc] init];

Comment: Try `Controls *ct = [[[Controls alloc] init] autorelease];` then.